# Count objects in array by property value and display result in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add the count number of `modelname` and append it to the `span` element. I first tried to target an ID with `length`, something like this, but I couldn't get it to work. What's the best way to do this?

```js
var modelCount = document.getElementById('#modelcount');
modelCount.innerHTML = productList.modelname.length;
```

```js
var productList = [{
  "model": "halvskap",
  "modelname": "Halvskåp",
  "type": "Standard",
  "typename": "Standard",
  "family": "Berlin"
}, {
  "model": "helskap",
  "modelname": "Helskåp",
  "type": "Parskap",
  "typename": "Parskap",
  "family": "Copenhagen"
}, {
  "model": "helskap",
  "modelname": "Helskåp",
  "type": "Parskap",
  "typename": "Parskap",
  "family": "Copenhagen"
}, {
  "model": "smafackskap",
  "modelname": "Småfackskåp",
  "type": "Standard",
  "typename": "Standard",
  "family": "Filippa"
}];
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="model" id="halvskap" value="halvskap">
    <label>Halvskåp</label>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="model" id="helskap" value="helskap">
    <label>Helskåp</label>
    <span id="modelcount"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="model" id="smafackskap" value="smafackskap">
    <label>Småfackskåp</label>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="model" id="zskap" value="zskap">
    <label>Z-skåp</label>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the data structure you have is not JSON. It's an array of objects. This may have affected the research you did.

Secondly there is no `Filippa` property in the object, but I assume this is just an error transcribing the code in the question, so I've added it in the example below.

To solve your issue you can loop through the array and increment the value in the relevant `span` based on the `model` value in the object. Try this:

```
productList.Filippa.forEach(o => $('#' + o.model).siblings('span').text((i, t) => (parseInt(t, 10) || 0) + 1));
```

Full working example:

```js
var productList = {
  Filippa: [{
    "model": "halvskap",
    "modelname": "Halvskåp",
    "type": "Standard",
    "typename": "Standard",
    "family": "Berlin"
  }, {
    "model": "helskap",
    "modelname": "Helskåp",
    "type": "Parskap",
    "typename": "Parskap",
    "family": "Copenhagen"
  }, {
    "model": "helskap",
    "modelname": "Helskåp",
    "type": "Parskap",
    "typename": "Parskap",
    "family": "Copenhagen"
  }, {
    "model": "smafackskap",
    "modelname": "Småfackskåp",
    "type": "Standard",
    "typename": "Standard",
    "family": "Filippa"
  }]
}

productList.Filippa.forEach(o => $('#' + o.model).siblings('span').text((i, t) => (parseInt(t, 10) || 0) + 1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="model" id="halvskap" value="halvskap">
    <label>Halvskåp</label>
    (<span>0</span>)
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="model" id="helskap" value="helskap">
    <label>Helskåp</label>
    (<span>0</span>)
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="model" id="smafackskap" value="smafackskap">
    <label>Småfackskåp</label>
    (<span>0</span>)
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="model" id="zskap" value="zskap">
    <label>Z-skåp</label>
    (<span>0</span>)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory. That  works perfect. And yes, that did affect my googlesearches. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice understanding of what OP's was trying to say.

Comment: I have 2 followup questions @RoryMcCrossan - I would liek to enclose the result in "()" but anything placedin my target div wont output. Whats the best way to do this? Second question, if i wanted to add another variable - lets say model + modelname - would that be much more complex? Thanks again!

Comment: Including parentheses around the values is simple, I've updated the example above to show you how. With regard to add other variables, then it's also straightforward. You just need to append them to the DOM where required. If you're stuck with this I'd suggest starting a new question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you. I placed parentheses inside the spans, but that didnt work. Outside worked. Will create a second question . Thanks again.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is it possible to do this without errors? Im using this with Google Tag manager and its giving me a esversion: ES6 compile error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count a specific modelname, you'll need to do a lambda. Try to use the filter function:

```js
var productList = [
  {
        "model": "halvskap",
        "modelname": "Halvskåp",
        "type": "Standard",
        "typename": "Standard",
        "family": "Berlin"   
    },
    {
        "model": "helskap",
        "modelname": "Helskåp",
        "type": "Parskap",
        "typename": "Parskap",
        "family": "Copenhagen"
    },               
    {
        "model": "helskap",
        "modelname": "Helskåp",
        "type": "Parskap",
        "typename": "Parskap",
        "family": "Copenhagen"
    },

    {
        "model": "smafackskap",
        "modelname": "Småfackskåp",
        "type": "Standard",
        "typename": "Standard",
        "family": "Filippa"
    }
];

var count = productList.filter(obj => obj.modelname == "Helskåp").length
console.log(count)
```

You can filter any object prop you want and get the length

Answer (score 0):

your javascript selector should be like this :

```
var modelCount = document.getElementById('modelcount');
modelCount.innerHTML = productList.length;
```

just remove `#` sign from your code.

Comment: Also, `productList.Filippa` probably is undefined. By the given json, the right should be `productList.length;`

Comment: Yes, I had a typo in there when I pasted the code here, sorry. Updated it.

Comment: @user3344734 that would also throw an exception.

Comment: It also doesn't get the number of items for each individual model.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how did you understand that from the question? LOL the issues OP didn't mention that, if I got 2 more downvote I will get one badge if I remove this answer! I will keep my answer anyway.